# Is it possible to execute a method from a module with a String ? - Ruby 2.7.1

Tags: ruby, string, methods, module, execute

Greetings to everyone.

This question is the continuation of a previous one :

[Is it possible to extend a class by using a string as a module ? - Ruby 2.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62700655/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-class-by-using-a-string-as-a-module-ruby-2-7-1)

So here it is. I am currently doing some tests with Ruby 2.7.1 on my FreeBSD 12.1 workstation. My objective is to find a way to load all the script within a directory. These scripts are modules with predictable names. For instance, if I got a script named mymodule.rb, it will contain a module named : Mymodule and a method : mymodule. So I can make a list of all scripts within a directory by using an Array. I can use that list to load/require all my script files easily. And with the help of some .sub, .chop or .capitalize, I can can extract what I need from each index of my array. But the result of this operation is always a String. The problem is that I cannot execute a method with a String. Previously I was having problem with extending my main class with module name from a String, but answers were given and solved this little issue. Here is my main class :

```
load "mymodule.rb"
class Myclass
  def mymethod
    var1 = "Mymodule"
    extend self.class.const_get(var1)
    var2 = "mymodule"
    #I need something here to call the method from the module.
    #puts @varmod
  end
end

a = Myclass.new
a.mymethod
```

and here is my module :

```
module Mymodule
  def mymodule
    @varmod = "TEST"
  end
end
```

So, I would like to know if there is a way to execute the method within Mymodule the same fashion we did with "extend self.class.const_get(var1)".

Thanks in advance for your responses !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#method-i-send) method your are looking for. The following should work:

```
send(var2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it completely solve my little issue !!!

Answer (score 2):

In order to send a message with a name that is not statically known at design time, you can use the [`Object#public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) method:

```rb
public_send(var2)
```

It is not necessary to use [`Object#send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) in this case, since your methods are not `private`.